# Using Crossfilter to Filter and Group for Histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to dc & crossfilter and am having some difficulty.

I have a data file with two dimensions, im and fm. Each range from `[0,1000000]`. However, I want to filter for the values between `[0,300000]` and then create a histogram.

Below is my code. When I enter `print_filter(grp)` into the console, i assumed it would show 6 groups, each of 50,000, between 0 and 30000. However it shows:

```
[object Object](17) = [
{"key":100000,"value":3776},
{"key":150000,"value":2192},
{"key":200000,"value":1098},
{"key":650000,"value":915},
{"key":800000,"value":824},
{"key":250000,"value":753},
{"key":500000,"value":652},
{"key":550000,"value":590},
{"key":900000,"value":567},
{"key":300000,"value":546},
{"key":350000,"value":538},
{"key":0,"value":527},
{"key":750000,"value":503},
{"key":400000,"value":483},
{"key":450000,"value":458},
{"key":600000,"value":299},
{"key":950000,"value":147}
]
```

which exceeds the 300,000 filter, and is also missing a "key" for 500000.

the code:

```
d3.csv("imfmincome.csv", function(data1) {
data = data1
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var byim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.parentincomeim; });
var byfm = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.parentincomefm; });
byim.filter([0,300000])
byfm.filter([0,300000])


var n_bins = 6;
var xExtent = [0,300000];
var binWidth = (xExtent[1] - xExtent[0]) / n_bins;
var grp = byfm.group(function(d){return Math.floor(d / binWidth) * binWidth;});

chart = dc.barChart("#barChart");
chart
    .width(200)
    .height(180)
    .margins({top: 15, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
    .dimension(byim)
    .group(grp)
    .round(Math.floor)
    .centerBar(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,300000]))
    .xAxis();

chart.xUnits(function(){return 10;});
chart.xAxis().tickValues([0,300000]);
```

my print function:

```
function print_filter(filter){
var f=eval(filter);
if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bins will still exist even if there are no values in them, so the range from 0 to 1,000,000 is not surprising.  The fact that there is no 500,000 bin probably just mean that there are no observations of 500,000-550,000.

What is surprising is that the bins above 300,000 do not have value 0. Although `byfm` will not observe its own filter, `byfm` will observe `byim`'s filter.

Is it possible that there are observations with high `parentincomefm` but low `parentincomeim`?

Comment: hmmm, there are a couple observations with high `fm` and low `im`, but the output is still strange. Thanks for the note on the bins existing even if they have no values - but nothing in my code looked blatantly weird or missing to you?

Comment: I found `print_filter` confusing; it seems to be trying to do a lot of things at once and it was unclear which path it follows. But other than that, looks reasonable I think. To test whether your filters are working correctly, you might try temporarily `byim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.parentincomefm; });` (ie point both dimensions to the same column) to see whether you get only the bins <300,000.

Comment: thanks for your replies. it turns out my mistake was even more beginner... i was importing the csv and the numbers were being recorded as strings and not numbers - which I assume made the filtering weird (that makes sense, yeah)? Thanks for the info on the filters bins, those were still helpful.

Comment: Ah yep, everyone runs into that one too.  Indeed "0" < "1000000" < "300000" :-D